# Transcript of Nightly Business Report on June 1, 2016

Tags: listening

I am reading the transcript from NBR.com

There are some sentences that I did not understand.

> Growth is seen weakening in the U.S. to below 2 percent and there was a little change in the **sub part over to** Europe and for Japan.
>
> The OECD even slashed its forecast for China **but it** nearly **a half a** point to 6.5 percent. The OECD calls it a low-growth trap.

It sounds like

```
...subpar outlooks for europe and for japan....

...slashed its forecast for China by nearly a half point to...
```

or

```
...slashed its forecast for China by nearly a half of point to....
```

You may watch the video which starts with 01:48

[Nightly Business Report - June 1, 2016 - YouTube:](https://youtu.be/MA-Zlc9GR8U?t=1m48s)

Also you may read the transcripts from NBR.com

[Transcript: Nightly Business Report – June 1, 2016](http://nbr.com/2016/06/01/transcript-nightly-business-report-june-1-2016/)

Thanks for your reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the transcript seems to be incorrect. I'm not entirely sure what he says because he did not enunciate, but I do believe that he says

> 1. subpar outlook**s** for Europe and for Japan

The reason why I think this is because he is reporting on a **forecast**, and so "outlook**s**" would be appropriate here. Also, I believe he uses the plural form of *outlook*: one for Europe, one for Japan.

He says

> 2. **by** nearly a half **a** point

So he says "a point" not "of point".

Comment: It's amazing to have someone to answer a question like this. Thank you for your confirmation. @Max

Comment: I looked up the word "outlook" in the dictionary. [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/outlook?q=outlook/) says that "outlook" is USUALLY singular.

Comment: Is "a half a point" a correct usage?  Thank you for having empathy with learners like US and giving constant feedback.  @Max

Comment: Yeah, but he is talking about one outlook for Europe and one outlook for Japan. So there are **two** outlooks. You can barely hear it. It sounds like a "z" and it is deemphasized. I don't know if it is "correct usage" but I feel like it is something people say, "a half a [noun]". I guess it is a reduction of "a half [of] a [noun]".

Comment: Wow! I heard /-z/ in the end of outlookS clearer after you mentioned that. And the explanation of "a half [of] a [noun]" you give makes everything perfect. I should keep in mind that the same thing like reduction might happen in other situations at least for Transcript of NBR.

Comment: Again I have to say thank you for your paying attention and listening to others' need. @Max and everyone here